# Is working in government insurance company right livelihood?

Tags: right-livelihood

I am currently jobless. I saw the advertisement of recruitment of government insurance company.  So I thought to ask before applying. I am very confused.  I don't want to do any wrong livelihood jobs.

Comment: While insurance can be beneficial when needed, in other cases it can sold in a fashion that takes advantage of customers (such as excessive premiums, limited coverage or delayed claims payments). Also some sales practices are misleading at best. Though this more likely involves for profit businesses, you probably won't know until you work there. Then based on the facts make a decision to continue or not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why wouldn't it be - it is not meat business or dealing with arms, or criminal activity, therefore isn't causing harm as a result of such business dealings.

After all, insurance is a positive thing as it helps the person in the case of unforeseen event.

Also here, [What is exactly Right Livelihood](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ajivo/index.html) as a reference from sutras. Furthermore, I advise watching [What is right livelihood by Ajahn Brahm](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZX18H8nw8JE&t=2280s) where it’s thoroughly explained.

From my perspective, make sure the company is not scammers and make it clear that your religion does not allow you to lie and twist the truth if sales is your department. Your intentions on why you work are important here.

Comment: How about financial services in general?

Comment: It is okay as long as you are helping someone and not do things that directly results in harm or deceit through lie. Watch Ajahn Brahm explaining Right livelihood https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZX18H8nw8JE&t=2280s

Answer (score 0):

I worked for two years for an insurance company, doing two jobs, namely, customer service when purchasing policies and insurance claims. It depends on the insurance company and how ethically it operates. I had no ethical issues in both of my jobs (particularly as I was able to negotiate outcomes). It was Right Livelihood. However, such jobs can easily become wrong livelihood if the organisation is unethical. I recommend to apply for the jobs and particularly focus on a task that has the least potential ethical conflict (such as customer service rather than claims).